# Autoscaling AWS spotfleet with terraform resets target capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, autoscaling, terraform-provider-aws

I have an `aws_spot_fleet_request` and an `aws_appautoscaling_target` to scale it. The problem is that after the fleet is auto scaled to new capacities, applying its terraform definition again wants to change the `target_capacity` back to the original value. This makes sense but is highly undesirable behaviour.

What would make more sense would be to omit the `target_capacity` attribute and allow the autoscaler to do everything but that's not possible since it's required.

A similar situation would occur on auto scaling groups but there the `desired_capacity` is not required and the terraform documentation makes a related [note](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_policy.html) too.

Comment: Can you share your Terraform code?

Comment: I'll be able by Monday :D

Answer (score 0):

Using [`ignore_changes`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#ignore_changes) on the attribute allows it to be used on creation and never again.